# MVC Partial View caching model id and name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, caching, partial-views, model-binding, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a partial view that is used in 2 places, one is using a view model within a post model with a manually added HtmlPrefix, so the field id looks like this:

```
id="Model_Address_AddressLine1"
```

In the other place I don't need a view model and the id is just "AddressLine1". It is the same partial view however.

However if i visit the page with "Model_Address_AddressLine1" first, IIS caches this partial view and then when I go to the other page it doesn't model bind and validate as the id is cached as "Model.Address.AddressLine1" and it doesn't pull "AddressLine1".

I have tried making the ajax call set to cache:false and set NoStore on the actions OutputCache attribute, but it still caches the partial views model ids and name, is there a way to stop it doing this?

Added this code if it helps, this is helper code that adds the prefix on one of the pages for the partial view, but not the other:

```
return helper.Partial(partialName, accessor.Compile().Invoke(helper.ViewData.Model),
                              new ViewDataDictionary(helper.ViewData)
                              {
                                  TemplateInfo = new TemplateInfo
                                  {
                                      HtmlFieldPrefix = prefix
                                  }
                              })
```

Response headers confirm caching:

Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:__RequestVerificationToken=qnKmH92lRoXCZWl_146N3uPiGRnWJCRZis6V_6cQ7mUJUdlVfAQVAxeTBtnhdTgM2s_NezoZghhwCrqBrv4GcjrCZr0XhG-6bHq7kfhlRrw1; ASP.NET_SessionId=dh225cux11sckpxl2uke30q3; FedAuth=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
Host:127.0.0.1:444
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36
Response Headersview source
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:9958
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Tue, 13 May 2014 08:15:52 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Vary:Accept-Encoding
X-Frame-Options:SAMEORIGIN

Comment: Do you have the caching and Outputcache set to false on both parent methods that call the partialview? Have you also ensured you have any browser caching turned off?

Comment: @SkyBlues87 They both call the same action in the same controller so yeh it was set for both. The browser doesn't cache it, because if I clear the browser cache, it still happens, IIS caches it, but can't switch it off.

Comment: Can you try NoCache attribute?

Comment: Can you post the http response headers from the page requests - In chrome, F12, Network, select page after request and then response headers.  I would be good to confirm the caching is working as required.

Comment: @SkyBlues87 added above

Comment: We've changed all the partials across the site to use the same structure and above helper to add the htmlfieldprefix as a result to make it work, not the ideal solution but its the only way around I can find. I think output caching is something different, this is compiler caching on the htmlfieldprefix and no idea how to stop this.

Answer (score 0):

**If you will change RenderPartial to RenderAction - even the OutputCache will works fine for you.** `[OutputCache(Duration=0)]`

I've used custom attribute for such purpose, it might be helpful for you too:

```
public class NoCache : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetValidUntilExpires(false);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetRevalidation(HttpCacheRevalidation.AllCaches);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();

        base.OnResultExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

---

M.b. Phil Haack's article [**"Donut Hole Caching in ASP.NET MVC"**](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/05/12/donut-hole-caching.aspx/) will also help you?

Comment: This came up a lot in my googling for this problem, but the output cache attribute doesn't work :(

Comment: I have this on the entire controller will this be sufficient? As doing that hasn't helped either

public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
        {
            if (filterContext == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("filterContext");
            }

            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow);
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
        }

Comment: Can you also try to change RenderParial to RenderAction?

Comment: same result with both :(

Comment: We've changed all the partials across the site to use the same structure and above helper to add the htmlfieldprefix as a result to make it work, not the ideal solution but its the only way around I can find. I think output caching is something different, this is compiler caching on the htmlfieldprefix and no idea how to stop this.